# Бесконечный цикл с разными интервалами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Уже наверное ясно что я ищу, но я еще раз опишу это. Задача создать нечто как setInterval, но что бы в нем можно было менять время задержки. 
Я пока надеялся что все можно сделать просто, но нет...

```
window.timeset = 1000; 

function play() {
el = $('.main');
num = parseInt(el.text());;
el.text(num+1);
window.timeset = Math.random();
}
setInterval(play, timeset);
```

Мне нужно будет не единоразово менять время, а каждый тик.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tогда Вам нужен не `setInterval`, а цепочка вызовов `setTimeout`.

```js
    function play() {
      var el = $('.main');
      var num = parseInt(el.text());
      el.text(num + 1);
      var timeout = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
      $("#timeout").text(timeout);
      setTimeout(play, timeout);
    }
    setTimeout(play, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Iteration = <span class="main">0</span>
<br />
Timeout = <span id="timeout"></span>
```

Comment: Таким образом можно менять 10 миллисекунд на другое значение? Как я говорил в самом начале - значений будет бесконечность и они будут генерироваться. Я проверил - у меня не вышло..

Comment: Мне нужен вечный скрипт с разными промежутками. Я сделал небольшую правку в посте, что бы было понятней что я хочу сделать.

Comment: `setInterval(play, Math.random());`  Кстати так наверное просто максимально подробно. Только лишь нужно что бы каждый раз были разные значения.

Comment: Большое спасибо, точно то что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Ещё можно использовать [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) – переданная туда функция будет вызываться при каждом «кадре» перерисовки экрана – и проверять текущее время: пора, или ещё нет в очередной раз «выстрелить».

Так время следующего срабатывания, в зависимости от слайдера, проверяется не только при следующем срабатывании, а часто-часто. Можно из крайнего правого «долгого» мигания мгновенно перебросить влево на частое мигание - и это сработает сразу. Правда, похоже, у вас немного другая задача, и достаточно варианта с `setTimeout()`.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('flash')
  ,out = document.getElementById('out-freq')
  ,slider = document.getElementById('in-freq')
  ,period
  ,state = 1
  ,start
  ,next
;

function step(timestamp) {
  period = parseInt( slider.value, 10);
  if (!start) start = timestamp;
  next = start + period;
  if( next < timestamp) {
    start = timestamp;
    next = start + period;
    out.innerHTML = slider.value;
    el.style.backgroundColor = (state ^= 1) ? "#F90" : "#333";
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
#flash {width:40px; height:40px; border-radius:20px; background-color:#CCC;}
```

```html
<input id="in-freq" type="range" min="10" max="500" step="10"> частота: <span id="out-freq"></span>
<div id="flash"></div>
```