# Как изменять время интервала в setInterval?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно что бы setInterval менялся по времени когда мне нужно допустим через программу менять длительность интервалов

Comment: Останавливать и запускать новый

Comment: никак, таймеры одноразвые их можно только запустить и отменить

Comment: В общем ответ дан тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506362/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8 А эту тему по идее закроют или как там с правилами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держать переменную со временем, когда должно произойти следующее срабатывание. В `setInterval()` указать совсем короткий промежуток, напр. 1/5 секунды. Внутри проверять, наступило ли уже время следующего срабатывания. Нет – выходим, есть – выполняется полезная нагрузка функции и устанавливается время следующего срабатывания.

```js
var interval = 800, next, div = document.getElementById('tick'), slider=document.getElementById('slider');

slider.value = interval;
slider.addEventListener( 'input', function(){
  interval = parseInt( slider.value);
});


function tack() {
  var now = (new Date).getTime();
  if( next  &&  next > now) return;
  next = now + interval;
  div.classList.toggle('black');
  
}

window.setInterval( tack, 100);
```

```css
#tick { width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid #333; }
.black { background-color:#333}
```

```html
<div id="tick"></div>

 <input id="slider" type="range" min="200" max="1000"/>
```